# Mysql procedure Illegal mix of collations problem

Tags: mysql

The problem is SQL request crush on my local machine but works fine on the stage machine. I figured out it is because I have procedures in my SQL request, but I can't find the needed settings to change on my local machine. I understand that it's a matter of collation but can't find a solution.

Original error message: 'Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=''

Comment: Have you looked into [COLLATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html)?

Comment: I tried it didn't work for me

Comment: Then I think we need more details. The SQL that gives the error and the table designs of the used tables.

Comment: I checked all tables and all them the same charset, in my sql i have 2 procedure and they couse the error i am sure.

Comment: SELECT M.imdbId, 
  getAvgMovieRateForUser(1340, M.imdbId) as reviewsRate, 
  getLatestMovieReviewIdForUser(1340, M.imdbId) as reviewId
FROM Reviews R
         LEFT JOIN Movies M ON R.movieId = M.imdbId
         LEFT JOIN UserUsers UU on R.userId = UU.userId
         LEFT JOIN Watchlists W on R.movieId = W.movieId and W.userId = 1340
         LEFT JOIN Reviews R3 on R.movieId = R3.movieId and R3.userId = 1340
         LEFT JOIN UserDeletedMovies UDM on R.movieId = UDM.movieId and UDM.userId = 1340
where (UU.userId = 1340 or UU.networkId = 1340)
  and M.imdbId = 'tt0000001'
........

Comment: Column collation differs from connection collation. Use explicit collation specifying in the query (like `WHERE column = 'literal' COLLATE needed_collation`) or change session collation setting.

Comment: I tried both approaches , no result, I temporary solved the problem using ssh tunnel to stage DB